# How do I add custom condition to an Azure DevOps task which is actually a Task Group?

Tags: azure-devops

Please, observe:

[image]

That's it. That is all a task that is a Task Group has. Compare that to just a task:

[image]

So what is the deal with the Task Groups? They look like a half-baked feature to me.

Comment: You can set conditions on the tasks inside a taskgroup. The issue is already tracked (https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/5112) but it looks like we won't get any updates for this in the next time, at least not for builds with the classic editor. i haven't yet checked out if this is possible to use in YAML-builds

Comment: Setting conditions on the tasks inside the task group is not even a workaround. Surely you realize it.

Comment: yeah i realize that but at the end of the day i have to get work done and i can't wait for Microsoft to address this properly

Comment: 2 years and 7 months later. Still no solution

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible to make this work with classic (non-YAML) pipelines. The trick is to use a PowerShell task as the first task in your task group, and within that task, set the value of a task variable. That task variable can then be used in the custom condition for other tasks in the group. e.g.

In the task group, create a PowerShell task as the first task with the following inline script:

```
if ($ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($(customCondition))) {
    Write-Host "evaluatedCustomCondition=true"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=evaluatedCustomCondition]true"
} else {
    Write-Host "evaluatedCustomCondition=false"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=evaluatedCustomCondition]false"
}
```

Then, in the custom condition for each subsequent task in the task group:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['evaluatedCustomCondition'], 'true'))
```

Then simply set the customCondition parameter value accordingly from the calling task, e.g.

```
'$(executeStep)' -eq 'true'
```

Please note that the customCondition value you're passing here should be in PowerShell syntax, and not the bespoke custom condition syntax (since it's going to be evaluated in PowerShell).

Answer (score 1):

> How to add custom condition to Azure DevOps task which is actually a Task Group?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

Indeed, this issue is already tracked on Github and Developer Community:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/5112

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/362353/implement-conditions-for-task-groups.html

And I checked the internal channel, found that it has been converted as part of an engineer's request. But, since the backlog for the next 2 months is full. MS team will try to pick up task group conditions feature after that. Currently this request is in a low priority.

As workaround, we could add the custom condition to each tasks in the task group, which is the workaround we are currently using. But you said it is not even a workaround. If you have any other issue with this workaround? You can share it in your question, so that we can check if we could find other better workaround.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Consider a function. I want to pass a filter predicate to the function, but instead I am going into its implementation and inserting the if inside wrapping each and every statement with it. (Of course, I wound never do it in C#, but Azure DevOps build task flow is not C#). Would you consider this acceptable? Task Group for me is a function. Someone else wrote it. Users are not supposed to change it. I am surprised it is not obvious. It is disappointing that Task Group is not a transparent substitution for a Task.

Comment: Another reason why it is not even a workaround is that by planting the condition inside the Task Group we effectively force all the instances of the same TaskGroup in the same build to follow the same condition structure. What if this is not the case? You need to start introducing all kinds of auxiliary variables to turn off parts of the condition that are not relevant. It is not maintainable.

Comment: @mark, Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for your detailed reply, I got it. Indeed, this is a issue. But there seems to be no better solution at the moment.